# SonarQube failed to start web

Tags: linux, sonarqube

I get the following error when I try to start SonarQube 7.7 on Linux.

```
WARN  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Fail to start web
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed     to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]
        at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:65)
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:51)
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:113)
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:100)
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:91)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:427)
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:61)
    ... 4 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9000]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util..LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You should provide more context. Is this a new installation, what did you change, what have you tried, did you add other plugins, ...

Comment: Downloaded SonarQube zip, unzipped it, changed permission for existing user; added username in `RUN_AS_USER`; and started it using start.sh file..

Comment: May [this](https://michalwegrzyn.wordpress.com/2016/07/14/do-not-run-sonar-as-root/) helps?

Comment: tried already..

Answer (score 7):

Did you change the property "sonar.web.port" in the sonar.properties file?

I had the same problem when I tried to set this property to port 80.
When not running as root user on unix systems it is not allowed to bind to a low port.

```
# TCP port for incoming HTTP connections. Default value is 9000.
sonar.web.port=8080
```

With the default port 9000 it should work.
As an alternative it is possible to forword the low port to the port on which the sonar webserver is running.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

Additionally this iptables configuration should be saved and restored after system restart. To achieve this, there exists different methos depending on the unix system.

Answer (score 0):

In the class ProcessEntryPoint.java there is a connection to a shared directory:

> public static final String PROPERTY_SHARED_PATH = "process.sharedDir";

Maybe you miss access rights. You could try to **start as root** for testing purpose or look for **sharedDir** in your **configuration**.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot start SonarQube as root.  ElasticSearch does not support that.